# About field extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra

$F$ is a field. Is $F[x]/ \langle (x-1) \rangle$ isomorphic to just $F$?

I was thinking by the following ways.

Any element of $\langle (x-1) \rangle$ can be expressed as $a_0+a_1(x-1)+a_2(x-1)^2+\dots+a_n(x-1)^n$, where $a_i \in F$ for i $1\le i\le n$.

Any element of $F[x]$ can be expressed as $b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2+\dots+b_nx^n$, where $b_j \in F$ for $1\le j\le n$ .

Any element of $F[x]/\langle x-1 \rangle$ should have a smaller degree than $x-1$, which would be only constant terms. With only constant terms, it will be isomorphic to $F$.

Is my reasoning correct? It seems like there are some missing links.

Also, is it shown that $\langle x-1 \rangle$ is in $F[x]$?

Thank you.

Comment: Your description of $\langle x-1\rangle$ is not correct (and the $\forall$ is not supposed to be used like that). But you are correct that any element in the quotient has a unique representative in $F[x]$ of degree at most $0$, which identifies the quotient with $F$.

Comment: I guess in other words, that, by the Euclidean algorithm in $F[x]$, the remainder when dividing by a degree-1 polynomial has to be a degree-0 polynomial, i.e., an element of $F$.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correct. A proof of this fact goes as follows: The ring homomorphism $\varphi: F[x] \rightarrow F$ that sends $x$ to $1$ is a surjective homomorphism whose kernel is the ideal generated by $x - 1$. To prove that the kernel is the ideal generated by $x - 1$, you need the fact that a polynomial $f(x)$ satisfies $f(1) = 0$ if and only if $x-1$ divides $f(x)$, and the proof of that statement relies on the Euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Yes; the map that sends $f(x)$ in $F[x]$ to its remainder when dividing by $(x-1)$ gives you the result. The elements of $F[x]/<(x-1)>$ are the remainders when dividing by $(x-1)$, and two elements $p(x),q(x)$are equivalent under the quotient if they bothe leave the same remainder when dividing by $(x-1)$. By the Euclidean algorithm, these remainders must have degree smaller than the degree of $(x-1)$ , i.e., the remainders must have degree $0$ , so they are elements of $F$.